# Flask __init__.py import error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I can not import functions from other files to `__init__.py` in a flask. Importing something from a file gets an error 500.

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from fel import fel

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**fel.py**

```
def fel(a,b):
    c = a+b
    return (c)
```

If I delete the following line in the `__init__.py` file

```
from fel import fel
```

Everything is OK.

`__init__.py` and `fel.py` are in the same directory

I am working in Python 3.4

Where is the mistake?
edit:
structures

```
FlaskApp\
  __init__.py  
  fel.py
```

Comment: What is the name of the package (directory)?

Comment: Are you expecting `from fel import fel` to be a Python 2-style relative import, importing the `fel` function from `whatever_your_package_is.fel`? Relative imports have to be explicit in Python 3.

Comment: Directory is FlaskApp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your import should be:

```
from FlaskApp.fel import fel
```

And the parent directory of `FlaskApp` needs to be present in your `sys.path` somehow (for example, set the PYTHONPATH environment variable).

Answer (score 4):

use relative import

```
from .fel import fel

fel(something)
```

Explanation:

> The problem of import fel is that you don't know whether its an
>   absolute import or a relative import. fel could a module in python's
>   path, or a package in the current module.

Source https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159503/whats-wrong-with-relative-imports-in-python

Answer (score -1):

just

```
from flask import Flask
from .fel import fel


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    number = fel(4,6)
    return (number)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Still error 500 I test on my digitalocean vps and pythonanywhere

Comment: -wim Yeah, you right is not the option but works for test

Comment: Ritero try this to test error:  comment fel import and into the hello_world add try: from fel import fel  except ImportError , e: return str(e)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help oskararenas  but the solution wim works for me :)